# Display javascript items one by one and have different delays

Tags: javascript, html

I have a header on an HTML page and I want to cycle once through a String array, and I got that down. But now my question is if it is possible to have a longer delay on one or two specific array items?

my code:

```
var sentences = [   "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
  var n = 0;

  setInterval(function() {
   if(n <= sentences.length) {
    document.getElementById("headerCH").innerHTML = sentences[n++];
    }
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: You also have problem of overshooting length of array. What is expectation when you run out of sentences?

Comment: Should help if I check first for the length of the array right?

Comment: where are you storing delays for each character ?

Comment: You give the setInterval function a general delay at the end so I don`t have separate delays stored.

Comment: Need to use individual `setTimeout` instead to accomplish this. Then you can modifiy the delay for each one based on whatever criteria you want. Could also have an array of delays and match sentence index to delay index

Answer (score 0):

```
var sentences = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
var n = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("el-id");

(function loop() {
    x.innerHTML = sentences[n];
    if (++n < sentences.length) {
        setTimeout(loop, 1000);
    }
})();
```

If you want separate delays for each character store them in array like below and change the setTimeout line to following

```
var delay = [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000];
setTimeout(loop, delay[n]);
```

This way you will be able to specify delays for each individual character if you want.

Answer (score -1):

```
var sentences = [   "1", "2", "3", "4", "5"];
 for(var n=0;n<sentences.length;n++){
if(n==1){
setInterval(function() {
 document.getElementById("headerCH").innerHTML =     sentences[n];
},2000);
}
else{
setInterval(function() {
document.getElementById("headerCH").innerHTML = sentences[n];
}, 1000);
}
if(n==4){n=0;}
}
```

Comment: Did you even try this? Will have as many setIntervals as length of array